# SQL query to get char from string based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string which I want to trim. What I am looking for is way to get the value from string up to the last `Y`.

Ex:

1. `AB Y bc Y dc Y1` -> `AB Y bc Y dc Y`
2. `ABYBCY` -> `ABYBCY`
3. `ABY BCY DC` -> `ABY BCY`

I am trying below query but I amn not getting what I need.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(200)='RAM, Y SHAM Y AB'
SELECT   @name
        ,right(@name, CHARINDEX('Y', @name) - 1) AS [Surname]
        ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(',', @name), LEN(@name)), ',', '') AS [FirstName]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `stuff()` and `reverse()`.

Something like this

```
SELECT STUFF(
           @name,
           LEN(@name) - CHARINDEX('Y', REVERSE(@name)),
           LEN(@name),
           ''
       ) string
```

**Note:**  This assumes that there is at least one "Y" in the given string.

[Here is a SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3494)

Comment: variable name is wrong - @name - please change in code

Comment: Yes code is working except two condition.. last 'Y' i have to append manually 2. In case there is no 'Y'

Comment: @Spenzo above given sample data is not working with Gordon's query..can you clarify on that..as it clearly mentioned need to remove values before last 'Y'

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something like:

```
Select substring(@name,1, len(@name) - (charindex('Y', reverse(@name)))+1)
```

Comment: You could even make it shorter by using LEFT instead of SUBSTRING

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING function we can achieve the result

```
declare @t table (Val varchar(30))
insert into @t (Val) values 
('AB Y bc Y dc Y1'),
('ABYCY1'),
('ABY BCY DC')

select REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Val),CHARINDEX('Y',REVERSE(Val)),LEN(Val)))
 from @t
```